# How to simplify second-order derivative of Ket in Dirac notation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, notation, perturbation-theory

I am currently playing around with Dirac notation in the context of interband transitions and came across a second derivative of a Ket. Under what conditions will this second derivative be zero: $\langle m | \ddot{n} \rangle = 0$? Or, what other simplifications can I make?

I am used to seeing people drop second-order terms in expressions, but I am not sure about that here. Maybe I can simplify by considering only linear $H$, and inserting the identity $\langle m | \dot{n} \rangle =\frac{\langle m | \dot{H} |\ n \rangle}{(E_n-E_m)}$? But it's not clear to me.

For a 2-band model, $|m\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$ are eigenstates from $H|m\rangle=E_m|m\rangle$, and the second derivative is with respect to some other parameter (such as momentum) that is not time.

Comment: Surely this depends entirely on what $|m\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$ are...?  Unless I'm missing something, this is like asking under what circumstances $\int_0^1 f(x) g''(x)  dx = 0$.

Comment: @J.Murray m and n are from $H|m> = E_m|m>$, for a 2-band model. I was wondering whether there were Hellman-Feynman-type identities (similar to what I specified at the end). So, it’s going to be specific to the system?

Comment: I just didn't know what they were - it would be a good idea to amend your question body with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Schroedinger equation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi\rangle=-\frac{i}{\hbar}H|\psi\rangle.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}|\psi\rangle=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(H|\psi\rangle)=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\dot{H}|\psi\rangle-\frac{i}{\hbar}H\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi\rangle\right)=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\dot{H}|\psi\rangle-\frac{1}{\hbar^2}H^2|\psi\rangle.$$
I'm not entirely sure what your $|m\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$ are (are they eigenstates of some time-independent part of the Hamiltonian?). Hopefully, this is enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modified my question to make it more specific. Apologies for the ambiguity.

Comment: What if I have a time-independent Hamiltonian? I worked out something like the Hellman-Feynman rules for off-diagonal elements, but it now involves the second derivative of the Hamiltonian. Let's say I have k controlling the Hamiltonian.